# MYSQL GROUP BY error in cartodb

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, cartodb

I'm using [carto](https://carto.com/) to try to visualize some geoJSON. Carto puts all of this data into a MYSQL database for you to query and display on a map. This may be helpful to know, but may not be important for solving my issue.

The important columns are `cartodb_id`, `the_geom` and `state`

The table name is `mcdonalds`

When I select from the mcdonalds table, I want to group all of the results by state. This is my current query:

`SELECT * FROM mcdonalds GROUP BY state;`

And I'm getting this error:

`Syntax error: column "mcdonalds.cartodb_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

I'm not too experienced with SQL, but from what I've seen on here, I need to do another select and join the tables? I've tried a few variations, hopefully this is an easy answer for someone.

Comment: Probably the sql_mode is set to `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` in which case the select can contain the column mentioned in the group by clause or aggregates. Anyway, why are you selecting all the columns directly while grouping by state... doesnt make any sense.

Comment: Sorry, still learning. This works fine: 

`SELECT cartodb_id, the_geom, state
from mcdonalds GROUP BY cartodb_id;`

But if i change the group by to state it gets the same error as described before:

`SELECT cartodb_id, the_geom, state
from mcdonalds GROUP BY state;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix your error you must do

> SELECT * FROM mcdonalds GROUP BY state, cartodb_id, the_geom;

Every column in the SELECT statement must be in the GROUP BY clause.